# StaleObjectStateException: Transaction Error in Grails

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have a TaskList entity with many workable Task entities and certain Tasks can "close" the TaskList.

```
class TaskList {
    ...
    static hasMany = [
        tasks: Task
    ]
}

class Task {
    ...
    static belongsTo = [taskList: TaskList]
}
```

Now when a Task is updated and it **can** "close" the TaskList, I make a `TaskListService` call to `closeList()`

```
class TaskListService {
    def closeList(TaskList taskList) {
        taskList.status = "CLOSED"
        taskList.save()
    }
}

// TaskController pseudo-update
def update () {
    Task taskInstance = Task.get(params.id)
    //... do something with the taskInstance
    taskListService.closeList(taskInstance.taskList)
}
```

My problem is when a user updates the TaskList entity while the `TaskListService` is updating it.

```
class TaskListController {
    def update () {
        TaskList taskListInstance = TaskList.get(params.id)
        //... do some stuff
        taskListInstance.properties = params
        taskListInstance.save(flush:true)
    }
}
```

> org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [com.giotta.TaskList#1]

How do I avoid this version conflict?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you expect concurrent edits, you have to use explicit locking. You're using optimistic locking, which is so named since you use it when you hope that there won't be concurrent edits, and that in rare cases where this happens you can just handle the problem.

Use the `lock()` method instead of the `get()` method and do the update after that. Note that locking only makes sense in a transaction, so pass the id to the service instead of the whole instance.

```
class TaskListService {
    def closeList(long taskListId) {
        TaskList taskList = TaskList.lock(taskListId)
        taskList.status = "CLOSED"
        taskList.save()
    }
}

// TaskController pseudo-update
def update () {
    Task taskInstance = Task.get(params.id)
    //... do something with the taskInstance
    taskListService.closeList(taskInstance.taskListId)
}
```

Here I'm using the `taskListId` dynamic property. You may need to change that to `taskInstance.taskList.id`

Comment: Thanks, Burt. I figured out I can perform the update via Hibernate event listeners. I'll definitely try your suggestion.

Comment: Unfortunately, your suggestion didn't work. I was able to update the Task, but the save of the TaskList raised the error again.

Comment: So, my problem was due to too many `flush: true` saves. I lighted the number of flushes and updated the update action to evaluate the version differently.